# What console command(s) will allow completion of the College of Winterhold quests?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have done the [College of Winterhold quests](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:College_of_Winterhold_%28faction%29#Primary_Quests) before and just wanted to use console commands to finish it again on a different character. What are the console command(s) to allow setting the quests as finished? Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/102242/visit-the-college-of-winterhold-quest-uncompletable

Comment: Can you check and see if that answers your question, I may be wrong.

Comment: I believe that question you linked is for the completion of the very first quest "Visit the College of Winterhold", not the entire questline.

Comment: @HelpDaSkyrimHelper By 'College of Winterhold quests', do you mean the '[Primary Quests](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:College_of_Winterhold_%28faction%29#Primary_Quests)' only? (i.e. minor quests not included)

Answer (score 2):

Console: `setstage <insert quest ID here> 200`

e.g. "College Objective Quest: Visit the College of Winterhold" = `setstage MG01Pointer 200`

Find the quest ID in the [UESP wiki](http://uesp.net/wiki/Main_Page).

[image]

If the last stage of the quest is more than 200 you can see it in the bottom of the quest page on UESP.